# Puppeteer's `waitForFileChooser()` doesn't detect filechooser launched Electron's API (Timeout)

Tags: electron, puppeteer

I have a test running on Puppeteer and it is trying to upload a file into my web app build using Electron.

My stack:

- Electron: v22
- Puppeteer: v19

I have in my `main.js` the following code

```js
function handleOpenFile(_, path) {
    const { canceled, filePaths } = await dialog.showOpenDialog({ path, properties: ['openFile'] 
    return filePaths[0] // assume user only chooses 1 file for this test
})
}
```

In my `preload.js`, it is exposed as a function:

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

window.electronAPI = {
    openFiles: (defaultPath) => ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog:openFiles', defaultPath),
}
```

My frontend code then calls this API under a button-press handler.

However, in my test, the code snippet will timeout even though a manual test proves that the file dialog does pop up.

```js
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForFileChooser(),
    page.qClick(UPLOAD_BUTTON),
]);
```

May I know what went wrong here?

I referred to their [Github issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/8615)

Answer (score 0):

Electron has 2 processes: The main process and the renderer process.

What went wrong was that Puppeteer was only able to communicate with the renderer process. Since the file dialog was launched from Electron's API, which comes from the main process, Puppeteer was unable to detect nor interact with it, thus the timeout.

You have to launch the file dialog from the renderer process (i.e. using vanilla html) for Puppeteer to detect the File Choooser.